# Obtener valores de un json , guardalos en una variable, json.parse()?

Tags: javascript, json, webservice

Hola estoy trabajando en un modulo que grafica datos con **Chart.js** , entonces charts.js trabaja con json, como casí todo el en le mundo, entonces estoy recibiendo otro **json** del cual pretendo tomar los datos que necesito para grafiarlos, entonces mi duda es la siguiente, alguien podría decirme como puedo tomar todos los campos **idCatSexo** por valor **1**, **2** y **NULL** , con ellos generar variables que me digan cuantas hay. No estoy seguro si mi mejor opción es utilizar un ...

> Json.Parce()

o algo similar para cumplir mi objetivo.

```js
// Json de Chart.js

//aquí es donde quisiera almacenar los datos del json
var dt = [nums_1, num_2, num_null];
var lb = ["valor 1", "valor 2", "valor null"];
var stackedLine = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: lb,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Datos',
      data: dt,
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
{
 "DatosEnvio": {},
 "DatosEnvioJson": {
  "Table1": {
   "campos": ["idCatSexo", "idSysCPEmpleados"],
   "datos": [{
     "idCatSexo": 2,
     "idSysCPEmpleados": 1
    }, {
     "idCatSexo": 2,
     "idSysCPEmpleados": 1
    }, dCatSexo ":1,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":52},{"
    idCatSexo ":1,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":53},{"
    idCatSexo ":1,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":54},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":55},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":56},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":57},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":58},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":59},{"
    idCatSexo ":1,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":60},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":61},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":62},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":63},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":64},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":65},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":66},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":67},{"
    idCatSexo ":1,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":68},{"
    idCatSexo ":1,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":69},{"
    idCatSexo ":1,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":70},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":71},{"
    idCatSexo ":1,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":72},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":73},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":74},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":75},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":76},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":2027},{"
    idCatSexo ":2,"
    idSysCPEmpleados ":2028}]},
    "Table2": {
     "campos": ["bandera", "mensaje"],
     "datos": [{
      "bandera": 0,
      "mensaje": "Se ingresaron los datos correctamente"
     }]
    }
   },
   "tablas": null,
   "bandera": "0",
   "mensaje": "--"
  }
```

Comment: ¿Podés agregar cuál es el resultado esperado?, es decir, que querés obtener del json recibido.

Comment: quiero saber cuantos 1'os , 2'os y null's hay y eso guardarlo en nums_1, num_2, num_null]

Comment: Supongo que te refieres a [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse)

Comment: upss hahaha listo ya lo edité

Comment: si , pensé qu epodría ser una opción pero no sé si sea la mejor para este caso ...

Comment: El json recibido está mal formado también.

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim primero verifica el JSON que este formado, como hcemos esto nosotros? generalmente yo uso una web que se llama [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) o un [plugins que instalo en chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener los valores de los elementos de tu json con el método [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/values). Esto suponiendo que tu json siempre tiene la misma forma y que los datos que te interesan siempre vienen en la misma posición del json. De esta forma, podés acceder al valor del elemento de la posición 1 (**datos**), del elemento 0 (**Table1**), del elemento 1 (**DatosEnvioJson**) de tu json recibido. Por ejemplo:

```
var cantidad1 = 0;
var cantidad2 = 0;
var cantidadNull = 0;

$.getJSON('jsn.json', function(myJson) {
            var datos = (Object.values(Object.values(Object.values(myJson)[1])[0])[1]);
            for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {

                if (Object.values(datos[i])[0] == 1) {
                    cantidad1++;
                } else if (Object.values(datos[i])[0] == 2) {
                    cantidad2++;
                } else {
                    cantidadNull++;
                }
            }
            alert("Cantidad de 1'os: " + cantidad1 + "\nCantidad 2'os: " + cantidad2 + "\nCantidad null's: " + cantidadNull);
        });
```

'json.json' es el json recibido. Después de esto, podés tener:

```
var dt = [cantidad1, cantidad2, cantidadNull];
```

```js
var jsonRecibido = {
  "DatosEnvio": {},
  "DatosEnvioJson": {
    "Table1": {
      "campos": [
        "idCatSexo",
        "idSysCPEmpleados"
      ],
      "datos": [
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 1
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 1
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 1,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 52
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 1,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 53
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 1,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 54
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 55
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 56
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 57
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 58
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 59
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 1,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 60
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 61
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 62
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 63
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 64
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 65
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 66
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 67
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 1,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 68
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 1,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 69
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 1,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 70
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 71
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 1,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 72
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 73
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 74
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 75
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 76
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 2027
        },
        {
          "idCatSexo": 2,
          "idSysCPEmpleados": 2028
        }
      ]
    },
    "Table2": {
      "campos": [
        "bandera",
        "mensaje"
      ],
      "datos": [
        {
          "bandera": 0,
          "mensaje": "Se ingresaron los datos correctamente"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "tablas": null,
  "bandera": "0",
  "mensaje": "--"
};

var cantidad1 = 0;
var cantidad2 = 0;
var cantidadNull = 0;

var datos = (Object.values(Object.values(Object.values(jsonRecibido)[1])[0])[1]);
   for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {

    if (Object.values(datos[i])[0] == 1) {
     cantidad1++;
    } else if (Object.values(datos[i])[0] == 2) {
     cantidad2++;
    } else {
     cantidadNull++;
    }
   }
   console.log("Cantidad de 1'os: " + cantidad1 + "\nCantidad 2'os: " + cantidad2 + "\nCantidad null's: " + cantidadNull);
```

Comment: Gracias hermoso ser divino